# Сервер печати в Ubuntu с виртуальным принтером

Tags: linux, сервер, cups

Задача подключить принтер для которого нет драйверов для современных ОС. Предполагаю следующий принцип действия:

1. На сервере устанавливается (пусть даже с бубном) принтер, далее на других ПК устанавливается виртуальный принтер который отправит pdf файл на сервер и проследит за его судьбой, т.е. постановка в очередь, снятие с печати и т.п.
2. Как бонус сохранять все файлы отправленные на печать на сервере.

Существуют ли какие нибудь готовые решения?

Comment: добавить принтер на сервер, с других компов поискать принтер по сети и добавить к себе ?

Answer (score 4):

Вам не нужен виртуальный принтер в linux.

На сервере с `cups` устанавливается и настраивается принтер через любые грабли, добивается его внятная работа. Затем правятся ACL для разрешения печати с нужных машин.

На клиентов ставится только `cups-client`, в `/etc/cups/client.conf` (штатно может не быть даже такой директории, как например в моём `debian`) пишется:

```
Encryption IfRequested
ServerName cups_server_host
```

Никаких драйверов на клиентах не нужно. Всё, печать в системе работает как будто принтер локален и даже штатно экспортирует свои настройки, вроде печати без полей, цветной/чернобелой печати (настройки зависят от драйвера на сервере, но на клиенте настройка для их поддержки не требуется)

Сохранение копий всех задач - лучше бы отдельным вопросом. Это явно вопрос к `cups`-серверу, но я подсказать не могу, не было такой задачи.

Comment: для виндовс клиентов актуально?

Comment: Не имею ни малейших представлений.